# GWT Designer. Does it work with later versions?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, swt, xulrunner

I'm starting a project in Eclipse Luna using GWT and GAE. I wanted to ask you if it is possible to run the GWT Designer(to make UI graphically) in GWT SDK 2.6 version.

UIBinder works fine, I mean the xml way. But when I try to make some UI with the designer, instead of writing source code in XML, it shows me the well-known error about SWT Browser and xulrunner. After reading and trying a lot of things I've come to the conclusion that you only can use it with Eclipse 3.7 and GWT 2.1 or olders. Am I right? Is there any other option to make UI with this technologies? (like you do in Xcode or Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT Designer is no longer maintained (in part because of those SWT Browser issues). That also implies that it doesn't work with GWT 2.7 (it didn't work with 2.6.0, and 2.6.1 temporarily reintroduced the code that GWT Designer needed, but GWT Designer was never updated so it stopped working with 2.7).

Because of all that, I wouldn't recommend even trying to make GWT Designer work with your current setup, as it's guaranteed to fail whenever you'll update either Eclipse or GWT.

I'm not aware of any other UI builder for GWT.

Last, but not least, according to the latest [GWT Survey](http://www.gwtproject.org/gwt_surveys.html), only 6% were using GWT Designer, vs. hand-editing plain Java code or UiBinder XML; this is not a big incentive to revive the GWT Designer project if you ask me…

Answer (score 0):

GWT Designer does indeed work with GWT 2.6.1 on Linux, but you need to install the WebkitGTK package.  If WebkitGTK is installed it will use that to render the browser; otherwise it uses xulrunner as a fallback, which doesn't work anymore as you have found.

Having said that, it can be a bit buggy at times.